# Drawing String with Graphics c#

Tags: c#, .net, system.drawing

how to draw string with graphics in c#? I tried with this code but it dose not work. Thanks.

```
g.DrawString("STRING", new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold), 
                       new Brush(), new Point(100, 100));
```

Error:

> Error 1   Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Drawing.Brush' C:\Users\Mihai\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\Graphics Drawtext\Form1.cs  33  73  Graphics Drawtext

Comment: Instead of passing new Brush() pass new SolidBrush(Color.Black)

Comment: that was it thanks!

Comment: Or use a standard Brushes.Black brush. If you create one of oyur own (makes only sense if you use a special color, esp. a semi-transparent color) do not forget to dispose of it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of abstract `Brush` you have to create concrete one - for example `SolidBrush` (or any other of your choice).

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush(v=vs.110).aspx) for the list of brush implementations (classes derive from `Brush`) you can use.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed it. i used " new SolidBrush(Color.Black) "

Comment: @Mihai, you may mark this as answer to indicate that it helped.

Comment: done, thanks very much.